# ZingChart bar chart is not generating correctly

Tags: angularjs, charts, zingchart

> html file

```
<zingchart id="timesheet-bar-chart" zc-json="myObj"></zingchart>
```

> in controller.js

```
$scope.myObj = {
  "type": "bar",
  "utc": true,
  "plotarea":{
      "margin":'dynamic'
    },
  "plot":{
    "stacked":true,
    "stack-type":"normal" /* Optional specification */
  },
 "scaleX":{
      "transform":{
        "type":"date",
        "all":"%d %M",
        "item": {
          "visible":false
        }
      },
    },
  "series":[{ 
      "values": $scope.barValues,
      "backgroundColor":"#f15662"
    }]
  };
zingchart.render({ 
id : 'timesheet-bar-chart', 
height: 400, 
width: "100%"
});
```

In $scope.barValues data is dynamically added in below format

> [[[1478025000000,10],[1477938600000,20],[1478889000000,30]]]

I'm not getting where I made any mistakes. The generated bar is not in format. please help me I'm using the ZingChart library for the first time.
[image]

Comment: What does "not in format" mean to you? The data plotted? The bar sizes? The scale labels? Please provide more detail as I cannot tell what you want to fix.

Comment: The bar size and x-axis scale labels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your bar chart is generating just fine. The bars look off from the labels because you are plotting an `[[]]` (array of arrays). If you look up the timestamps plotted the bars are indeed not plotted exactly at November 4th. If you are referring to the labels themselves you determine what the label is displayed by the `all` attribute. You can either set the `step` attribute to be more linear or use zooming.

[scale docs](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/tutorials/chart-elements/configure-chart-scales/#scale-types-time-series-scale)

[token docs](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/tutorials/chart-elements/zingchart-tokens/#time-series-tokens)

The bar offset is a product of non-linear data. The bar size is now squeezed smaller because of the non-linear data as well. This is due to size over time. You can see by adding `zooming` (click and drag to zoom) the bars will increase size.

[zooming docs](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/tutorials/interactive-features/chart-zoom-pan-scroll/)

```js
var myConfig = {
  "type": "bar",
  "utc": true,
  "plotarea":{
      "margin":'dynamic'
    },
  "plot":{
    "stacked":true,
    "stack-type":"normal" /* Optional specification */
  },
 "scaleX":{
   "zooming":true,
      "transform":{
        "type":"date",
        "all":"%d %M %Y<br> %h:%i:%s",
      },
    },
  "series":[{ 
      "values": [[1478025000000,10],[1477938600000,20],[1478889000000,30]],
      "backgroundColor":"#f15662"
    }]
  };

zingchart.render({ 
 id: 'myChart', 
 data: myConfig, 
 height: '100%', 
 width: '100%' 
});
```

```css
html, body {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
#myChart {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 min-height:150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="myChart"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

You can avoid this by setting a fixed size with the `bar-width` attribute.

[plot docs](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/api/json-configuration/graphset/plot/)

```js
var myConfig = {
  "type": "bar",
  "utc": true,
  "plotarea":{
      "margin":'dynamic'
    },
  "plot":{
    "bar-width": 30,
    "stacked":true,
    "stack-type":"normal" /* Optional specification */
  },
 "scaleX":{
   "zooming":true,
      "transform":{
        "type":"date",
         "all":"%d %M %Y<br> %h:%i:%s",
      },
    },
  "series":[{ 
      "values": [[1478025000000,10],[1477938600000,20],[1478889000000,30]],
      "backgroundColor":"#f15662"
    }]
  };

zingchart.render({ 
 id: 'myChart', 
 data: myConfig, 
 height: '100%', 
 width: '100%' 
});
```

```css
html, body {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
#myChart {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 min-height:150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <!--Assets will be injected here on compile. Use the assets button above-->
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="myChart"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```